# Ionic Camera Plugin asks for location permission

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-camera, ionic-native, ionic5

I am using Ionic and angular to make a android app to click picture.
When I call the ionic-native/camera API, my android phone asks for camera and location access.
My question is that why does clicking a picture ask for location?
My Code

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from "@ionic-native/camera/ngx";

......

constructor(
    private camera: Camera,
  ) {}

....

ngOnInit() {
const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    };
 this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      (imageData) => {
        this.Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        this.Event.emit(this.Image)
      },
}
```

My versions/dependencies

```
"@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^5.28.0",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
```

My code is working fine, the native camera is opening up, my question is why is it asking location permission to open camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is collecting location details to store in the EXIF data of images.

Normally, all images taken in camera have GPS coordinates or some form of location details.

[image: Example Image]

Some stock camera apps has this permission as mandatory making it compulsory for that permission required to open the app. You should check if such permission can be disabled in the stock camera app and then try if you want to deny location permission.

Comment: Thanks, I found a link for more information on the specific plugin I was using. https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/camera#preferences-ios-. I found how to do it for iOS. I will try to find one for android and add it to the comment here